# Unable to create ec2 instance using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
vpc = ec2.Vpc('vpc-xxxxx')
subnet = ec2.Subnet('subnet-xxxxx')
security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup('sg-xxxxx')
key_pair = ec2.KeyPair('xxxx')
instance = ec2.create_instances(
ImageId='ami-43a15f3e',
MinCount=1,
MaxCount=1,
InstanceType='t2.micro')
print (instance[0].id)
```

Just tried to create instance by running the above boto3 script. Its failing with below error. Any help on this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boto2.py", line 12, in <module>
    InstanceType='t2.micro')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (VPCIdNotSpecified) when calling the RunInstances operation: No default VPC for this user
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [boto3 documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances):

> [EC2-VPC] If you don't specify a subnet ID, we choose a default subnet from your default VPC for you. If you don't have a default VPC, you must specify a subnet ID in the request.

You have to provide the subnet ID to the `create_instances` function if you don't have a default VPC, and according to your error, it looks like you don't have a default VPC.

Try to run:

```
instance = ec2.create_instances(
ImageId='ami-43a15f3e',
MinCount=1,
MaxCount=1,
InstanceType='t2.micro',
SubnetId='subnet-xxxxx')
```

Comment: Getting below error.                                                                       File "boto2.py", line 13
    print (instance[0].id)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I've missed a comma after the InstanceType line (edited the answer), fix it in your code as well.